# python for loop doesn't remove both items within an array

Tags: python

I want to remove all websites that have the following strings contained in the `remo` array, however it only removes the first index. here is what i have so far.

How would i be able to remove both items in the array ?

So far it removes urls containing "listings"

```
with open('example.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter= ",")
    websites = set()
    phonenumbers = set()
    data = ["gutter"]
    # remove urls that have these strings,  only works with the first string but not second one.
    remo = ["listings",  "nationwide"]
    for row in readCSV:
        website = row[2]
        phonenumber = row[0]
        if website not in websites:
            for x in data:
                if x in website:
                    for r in remo:
                        if r not in website:
                            websites.add(website)
```

Comment: you're not trying to remove anything

Comment: then how come it remove urls that have a `listings' string ?

Comment: You need to check that **all** the strings in `remo` aren't in `website` before adding it: `if all(r not in website for r in remo): websites.add(website)`.

Comment: this works now, however i do not understand the logic and why it works....

Comment: @BARNOWL. What will happen when a url *does not* contain "listings", but *does* contain "nationwide"?

Comment: its omitting 'listings, nationwide' it will not be written on the csv row.

Comment: @BARNOWL. No - your code will add it to `websites` when it does not contain "listings", even though it also contains "nationwide". As I said: you need to check them **all** before adding.

Comment: it works, so im satisfied, thanks. just don't understand why it works.

Comment: Seems like a filter problem that could be solved with filter() or list comprehension, then throw it into set() to remove duplicates. Generally speaking of course.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that after finding no "listings" string in the URL, it adds it to the list, THEN it checks if "nationwide" is in it.
Try this:

```
for r in remo:
  if r in website:
    break
else: # note: this is indented to the for loop.
  websites.add(website)
```

This way it will execute the whole for loop - checking for each word in the remo array. If none of them are present, the for loop will reach a natural end and the else statement will execute.
However, if a value of the remo array is found, the for loop will be broken, and the else statement will not execute.

Comment: only removes the first item in the array, but this seems to work `if all(r not in website for r in remo):
       websites.add(website)`

Comment: If you look closely my code is slightly different from yours. The if all statement is a shorthand I was unaware of so I'm grateful to find it here.

Comment: no worries man, i found the solution using `if all(r not in website for r in remo): websites.add(website)`

Answer (score -1):

You can just collect all websites in set and in the end subtract remo set from it:

```
filtered_websites = websites - set(["listings",  "nationwide"])
```

Comment: Read the question again: `websites` is a list of **urls**.

Comment: Sure - but it contains ***URLS***, not simple words.